# Переключение представлений в XAML

Tags: xaml, .net

Задача такая. Есть два представления, которые должны отображаться попеременно. Переключение представлений должно происходить по двум кнопкам: когда выбрана первая кнопка, отображается первое представление, когда выбрана вторая кнопка, отображается второе представление. Каждое представление вынесено в отдельный UserControl.

Как правильно делать подобные вещи из XAML, не затрагивая C# код?

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать коллекцию представлений и связать ее с элементом ListBox. Примерно так.

```
<!-- Это шаблон данных, применяемый к представлению -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:SomeViewModel}">
    <Views:SomeView />
</DataTemplate>

<!-- Это переключатель, который может содержать ряд из ToggleButton -->
<ListBox 
    x:Name="ModesListBox" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Modes}" 
/>

<!-- Это переключаемые представления -->
<ContentControl 
    Content="{Binding ElementName=ModesListBox, Path=SelectedItem}"
/>
```